# Showing the image of $H^j(X;\mathbb C^\times)$ lies in the torsion subgroup of $H^{j+1}(X;\mathbb Z)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a (compact, if necessary) topological space.  Then from the short exact sequence of constant sheaves
$$
0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^\times \to 0
$$
we have a connecting homomorphism
$$
H^j(X;\mathbb C^\times) \to H^{j+1}(X;\mathbb Z).
$$
What is a good way of seeing that the image of this map is contained in the torsion subgroup of $H^{j+1}(X;\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: By $\mathbb{C}$ do you mean a sheaf of locally constant functions into $\mathbb{C}$, ie. you disregard the topology on complex numbers..? If so, did you try the simpler short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$..? It will show equivalent behaviour, but is much smaller.

Comment: Yes, I mean the sheaf of locally constant functions.  I haven't thought about that sequence.  It seems there should be a very simple and general reason for why this holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm being silly, the torsion subgroup is contained in the kernel of the map $H^{j+1}(X,\Bbb Z)\to H^{j+1}(X,\Bbb C)$, so you're done by exactness of the long exact sequence. (For reasonable spaces, e.g., manifolds or simplicial complexes, the sheaf cohomology and singular cohomology agree.)

Comment: Ugh yea I really should have seen that!  Thanks!